# Caching a lot of data in offline React app has been causing performance problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I think I hit wall with my app architecture in React and really need some help.

I have build offline first app which on first start fetch all data from server, store it localy in indexed db and then load it to React state. This way it works also without internet connection.

When user create data, it is first stored localy, then synced with server.
Updates fetch only new data.

So far it works, but when I started to work with hundreds of record, I am hitting performance problems. As I work with browser's storage and not server when querying, I am always working with all data in indexed db and can't use magic of pagination to get only needed data.

For example I have 3000 documents which each belongs to like 30 folders.
On load, I need to link them with folders, sort them and then filter them under folders. Maybe add some more loops for calculations for something like subdocuments, etc, etc.

This obviously doesnt scale well as I need to loop many times over documents array to get desired result.

I think I have only three options but would like to hear what would you suggest:

1. Optimize loops and try to cut some of them (this will just push line for performance problem higher but doesnt solve it)
2. Ditch offline capability all together, cache only few items or one "view" (last opened documents, last filter, etc) and get all other items from server. With fewer data, calculations will be much faster at client side.
3. Cache filtered result with all calculations and sorting. As app is content creating/updating heavy this only helps a little as those calculations would be soon dated and needed to be still redone. This could help with app starting time, but not with flow performance due to constant recalculations of data.
4. bonus - I could split array with data to smaller parts before using them in React state for further calculations and sorting, but I would still need to preselect them with looping

Thank you